# How do I tell cmake to separate the solution and the project?

Tags: c++, visual-studio, cmake

I have a CMakeList.txt that works, but it doesn't separate the solution from the project, and this is quite ugly. I'd like to tell to cmake to make a folder for the project. That way it will be easier to understand the folder when we generate it with cmake.

Rigth now it looks like this :

[image: How cmake generates the folder]

Is it possible to generate it like this ? :
[image: every project files are in zProject folder]

Here's what my Cmake list looks like :

```
cmake_minimum_required( VERSION 3.1 FATAL_ERROR )
# Create Project
project(PointCloudToRndConvertor)
add_executable( PointCloudToRndConvertor main.cpp )
set_property( DIRECTORY PROPERTY VS_STARTUP_PROJECT "PointCloudToRndConvertor" )

# Find Packages
find_package( PCL 1.9.1 REQUIRED )

if( PCL_FOUND )
  # Additional Include Directories
  # [C/C++]>[General]>[Additional Include Directories]
  include_directories( ${PCL_INCLUDE_DIRS} )

  # Preprocessor Definitions
  # [C/C++]>[Preprocessor]>[Preprocessor Definitions]
  add_definitions( ${PCL_DEFINITIONS} )
  add_definitions( -DPCL_NO_PRECOMPILE )

  # Additional Library Directories
  # [Linker]>[General]>[Additional Library Directories]
  link_directories( ${PCL_LIBRARY_DIRS} )

  # Additional Dependencies
  # [Linker]>[Input]>[Additional Dependencies]
  target_link_libraries( PointCloudToRndConvertor ${PCL_LIBRARIES} )
endif()
```

Answer (score 0):

You can set folder where target suppose to be visible by changing its property:

```
set_target_properties(
    yuor_target
    PROPERTIES FOLDER SomeFolderWhereItShouldGo
)
```

References:

- [FOLDER](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/prop_tgt/FOLDER.html)
- [set_target_properties](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/command/set_target_properties.html)